# Вынос методов вложенного класса за пределы классов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток. Имеется шаблонный класс:

```
    template<class T> 
        class List
        {
        struct Node
            {
                T elem;
                Node* next;
                Node* prev;

                Node();
            };
            int count;
            Node* head;
            Node *tail;
        public:
    // методы
};
```

Также, имею вложенный обычный класс-итератор:

```
class Iterator
    {
        Node* element;
    public:
        // Конструкторы и перегрузки
        Iterator(const Iterator&); // инициализация итератором
        Iterator(Node*); // инициализация узлом
        Iterator& operator=(Node* node) // присвоение узла
        {
            if (*this == &node)
                return *this;
            this->elem = node;
            return *this;
        }

        // Манипулирование
        bool hasNext(); // есть ли следующий
        bool hasPrev(); // есть ли предыдущий
        T next(); // к следующему
        T prev(); // к предыдущему
    };
```

Простой класс. Каким образом вынести реализацию перегруженного operator= из класса Iterator за его пределы, и пределы класса List? Пробовал много-чего, ошибки довольно странные:
Ошибка  C2143   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"

Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В классическом синтаксисе

```
template <class T> 
typename List<T>::Iterator &List<T>::Iterator::operator =(Node *node)
{
  ...
}
```

Обратите внимание, что квалифицированное имя `List<T>::Iterator` (и, как следствие, ключевое слово `typename`) требуется только в типе возвращаемого значения. В списке параметров можно использовать "короткие" имена типов, т.е. `Node`.

В С++11 также можно записать так (не поддаваясь пока на соблазн использовать С++14 дедукцию возвращаемого типа)

```
template <class T> 
auto List<T>::Iterator::operator =(Node* node) -> Iterator &
{
  ...
}
```

В таком синтаксисе нет необходимости использовать квалифицированное имя (и `typename`) в типе возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку! Единственное, что хотелось бы понять, так это следующее:
Почему мы пишем перед конструкцией typename?
Я, собственно, так и делал...кроме ключевого typename

Comment: Когда вы указываете вложенный тип шаблонного класса и при этом не все параметры конкретизированы, то надо добавлять `typename`. В данном случае для ссылки на `List<T>::Iterator` нужен префикс `typename`. А вот для ссылки на `List<int>::Iterator` уже не нужно `typename`, т.к. все параметры шаблона "зафиксированы".

Comment: Благодарю, все стало понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Если не акцентировать внимание на реализацию этого оператора, то он может быть определен следующим образом

```
template <class T>

typename List<T>::Iterator & List<T>::Iterator::operator =( typename List<T>::Node *node )
{
    if ( this->element != node ) this->element = node;
    return *this;
}
```

Или более просто

```
template <class T>

typename List<T>::Iterator & List<T>::Iterator::operator =( Node *node )
{
    if ( this->element != node ) this->element = node;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Действительно, реализовать оператор можно проще, просто как-то не задумывался, сделал стандартной записью. Благодарю.