# Проблема с шаблонами

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Скажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не получается реализацию интерфейсов с шаблонами сделать?

**Queue.h**

```
#ifndef UNTITLED104_QUEUE_H
#define UNTITLED104_QUEUE_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node{
private:
    T value;
public:
    Node *next_node, *back_node;

    Node():next_node(NULL),back_node(NULL){};
    Node(T new_value):value(new_value),next_node(NULL),back_node(NULL){};

    T getValue();
    void setValue(T new_value);
    void deleteNode();
    Node* getNext();
    Node* getBack();
};

template <typename T>
class Queue{
private:
    Node<T>* firstNode=NULL;
    unsigned size=0;
public:
    Queue(T value);
    Node<T>* getFirst();
    Node<T>* getNode(int position);
    unsigned int getSize();
    Node<T>* insert_after(int position, T value);
};

#endif //UNTITLED104_QUEUE_H
```

**Queue.cpp**

```
#include "Queue.h"

template<typename T>
T Node<T>::getValue() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
void Node<T>::setValue(T new_value) {
}

template<typename T>
void Node<T>::deleteNode() {
}

template<typename T>
Node *Node<T>::getNext() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Node *Node<T>::getBack() {
    return nullptr;
}




template<typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue(T value) {
}

template<typename T>
Node<T> *Queue<T>::getFirst() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T> *Queue<T>::getNode(int position) {
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
unsigned int Queue<T>::getSize() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T> *Queue<T>::insert_after(int position, T value) {
    return nullptr;
}
```

**Ошибки:**

```
C:\Users\Alex\CLionProjects\untitled104\Queue.cpp:21:1: error: invalid use of template-name 'Node' without an argument list
 Node *Node<T>::getNext() {
 ^
C:\Users\Alex\CLionProjects\untitled104\Queue.cpp:26:1: error: invalid use of template-name 'Node' without an argument list
 Node *Node<T>::getBack() {
 ^
```

Comment: Так компилятор же написал, в чем ошибка. Забыли список шаблонных аргументов: `<T>`.

Comment: Но дальше вы все равно столкнетесь с [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).

Comment: Это не дубликат вашего вопроса, но посмотрите обязательно сюда - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12586/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-cpp

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655897/Вынос-методов-вложенного-класса-за-пределы-классов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто `Node` является синонимом `Node<T>` только в области видимости класса. За пределами этой области видимости придется всегда использовать "полный" синтаксис `Node<список аргументов шаблона>`.

Если определение метода шаблона `Node<T>` делается за пределами шаблонного класса, то по вышеприведенной причине в типе возвращаемого значения вы уже не сможете сокращать `Node<T>` до `Node` при использовании "классического" синтаксиса. Правильно

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> *Node<T>::getNext() {
    return nullptr;
}
```

Однако если спецификация шаблонного типа длинна и вы не хотите повторять ее дважды, вы можете воспользоваться новым синтаксисом

```
template<typename T>
auto Node<T>::getNext() -> Node * {
    return nullptr;
}
```

В этом случае вы можете использовать справа "короткое" имя `Node`.

И, как вам уже сказали, определения шаблонных сущностей не следует выносить в `.cpp` файл. Даже если вы делаете их за пределами класса, то их все равно следует поместить в заголовочный файл, рядом с определением класса.

---

Дополнительная `;` после определения метода в классе

```
Node():next_node(NULL),back_node(NULL){};
                                        ^
```

не является ошибкой, но является ненужным пустым объявлением.

Также не ясно, почему в одном классе вы пользуетесь инициализаторами для полей прямо в определении класса, а в другом упорно отказываетесь.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что классу `Node` не хватает аргумента шаблона. Исправьте тип полей `next_node` и `back_node` на `Node<T> *`, а также возвращаемый тип методов `getNext` и `getBack`.

Comment: Конкретно тип полей исправлять исправлять нет необходимости. Внутри определения шаблона класса можно не указывать шаблонные аргументы для этого класса, тогда они подставляются автоматически. См. [injected-class-name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

Comment: Тип полей исправлять не нужно. Внутри области видимости класса `Node` является синонимом `Node<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, следует поместить полностью определения шаблонных классов (включая их членов) в заголовок.

Во-вторых, в некоторых функциях вы забыли определить шаблонный идентификатор.

```
template<typename T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::getNext() 
{
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::getBack() 
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Ниже представлен заголовок с соответствующими внесенными изменениями.

```
#ifndef UNTITLED104_QUEUE_H
#define UNTITLED104_QUEUE_H

#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node
{
private:
    T value;
public:
    Node *next_node, *back_node;

    Node() : next_node( nullptr ),back_node( nullptr )
    {
    }

    Node( const T &new_value ) : value( new_value ), next_node( nullptr ), back_node( nullptr )
    {
    }

    T getValue() const;
    void setValue( const T &new_value );
    void deleteNode();
    Node* getNext();
    Node* getBack();
};

template <typename T>
class Queue{
private:
    Node<T>* firstNode = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
public:
    Queue( const T &value );
    Node<T> * getFirst();
    Node<T> * getNode( size_t position );
    size_t getSize() const;
    Node<T> * insert_after( size_t position, const T &value );
};

template <typename T>
T Node<T>::getValue() const
{
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::setValue( const T &new_value ) 
{
}

template <typename T>
void Node<T>::deleteNode() 
{
}

template<typename T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::getNext() 
{
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::getBack() 
{
    return nullptr;
}


template <typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue( const T &value ) 
{
}

template <typename T>
Node<T> * Queue<T>::getFirst() 
{
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T> * Queue<T>::getNode( size_t position ) 
{
    return nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
size_t Queue<T>::getSize() const 
{
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T> * Queue<T>::insert_after( size_t position, const T &value ) 
{
    return nullptr;
}

#endif //UNTITLED104_QUEUE_H
```